# Chart json data from url on iOS

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, charts

How can i chart json data from a url in iOS ?
Is there a iOS chart framework that does this automatically? 
i don't know the answers to these questions but I'm open to anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iOS has built in framework for parsing JSON `NSJSONSerialization`
take a look at these tutorials to know how to use them

[Pasrsing JSON using NSJSONSerialization Link 1](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/03/06/parsing-json-in-objective-c-using-nsjsonserialization/)

[Pasrsing JSON using NSJSONSerialization Link 2](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/)

[Pasrsing JSON using NSJSONSerialization Link 3](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json-in-ios6/)

there are also other frameworks for this purpose